# How many rolls of the die on average in this game

Tags: probability

My maths problem is best explained in terms of this made up die game.

If I cast an eight sided die once and the numbers 2-8 appear then the game is over and I have threw the die once. If however I cast a 1 then I get 5 more throws of the die. If I only throw a 2-7 in these 5 throws then the game is over and I threw the dice 6 times. If however I throw another 1 at any point during these 5 throws then the number of throws I have left is reset to 5 (note the number is reset to 5 and not an additional 5 added to the remaining tally). This continue until 5 consecutive 2-8 are thrown, then the game is over.

Is there a formula that can be used to calculate for each game on average how many times can I expect to roll the die?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You could describe this as an [absorbing markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain).  The fundamental matrix would have the information you seek.

Comment: Thanks, does the question become easier to answer if I did away with the first roll and simply started with 5 throws?

Comment: You could treat the first roll the same as the state that you have thrown "large numbers" four times in a row already.  As such, you can describe this as a six-state absorbing markov chain with states $A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, B$, where $A_i$ represents the event that the length of the current streak of large numbers is $i$, and $B$ is the end state.  You would have probability of moving from $A_i$ to $A_{i+1}$ as $\frac{7}{8}$ for each $i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, from $A_4$ to $B$ as $\frac{7}{8}$, from $B$ to $B$ as $1$, and from $A_i$ to $A_0$ as $\frac{1}{8}$.  Initial state $A_4$.

Comment: Thanks for your help this worked great. I calculated the transition matrix. The identity matrix and the formal matrix to get the answer. Is there a way to use any of this data to calculate what percentage of games played will use n steps to get to the absorption state? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you keep playing this game until you have rolled the die $N$ times, where $N$ is a very large number.

Now divide the sequence of rolls into subsequences so the first roll in each
subsequence is a $1$ and all other rolls are greater than $1$.
(Ignore any rolls before the first $1$.)
You can expect there to be $N/8$ such subsequences.
Of those subsequences, some number can be expected to be of length $1$,
a smaller number of length $2$, an even smaller number of length $3$,
and so forth.
(I believe the formula is the expected number of subsequences of
length $k + 1$ is $7/8$ times the expected number of length $k$.)

Consider the kind of game that stops if you roll anything but $1$ on the first roll.
Subsequences of length $5$ or less represent parts of games that ended
in a later subsequence.
A subsequence of length $6$ contains the end of a game;
a subsequence of length $7$ contains the ends of two games
(five failures after the last $1$, ending one game, and then a roll
greater than $1$, ending a second game).
In general, a subsequence of length $k$ ($k \geq 6$)
contains the ends of $k - 5$ games.

From the expected number of subsequences of each length, weighted by
the number of games ending during each subsequence, we can get the
expected number of games in $N$ rolls of the die.
Speaking a little more precisely, we get the ratio of the
expected number of games to $N$ as $N$ goes to infinity.

Let that ratio be $g$. Then the expected length of each game is $1/g$.

But if you don't trust this analysis, a Markov chain should work too.